# pom.xml parent tag error

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to create spring boot application in my local using maven. Bit im getting below error.

```
**Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for io.spring.boot.quickstart:course-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.2-RELEASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM**
```

Pom.xml :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2-RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Even I tries to delete .lastmodified and update project. But no luck.

Comment: Do you have any changes in your settings.xml? or do you have any configurations in your pom file for repositories?

Comment: Does parent pom file of spring-boot-start-parent exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is incorrect. Correct one is:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It's `1.4.2.RELEASE` and not `1.4.2-RELEASE`.

By the way your version is quite old. Latest one is `2.0.4.RELEASE`. If you want to keep backward compatibility, you can increase the patch version to 7, i.e. `1.4.7.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Project Tab on Eclipse and Select Clean.
Then Eclipse will automatically remove the Maven Dependencies and re-build your project. By then, the error may be gone.

[Top Section after File-Edit-Navigate-Search. You will find Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e57Y4.png)